# How to use the Mathematical operations in my Array inside my Random Quiz Python 3, I want to use all the operations in my array in that order

Tags: python-3.4, python-3.5

This is my Maths Quiz, what my problem is is that **I want to use all the operations in my array in that order**. This is my code so far:

```
import random
import time
Rand1= 0
Rand2= 0
name = input("What is your name?")#Asks the user for their name
print("Welcome to a small maths test",name,"have fun and good luck!")#Welcomes the user with the name whith the name which they have input
def Question():
    QuestionsAsked = 0
    operation = ["+","+","+","+","-","-","-","*","*","*"]
    Addscore = 0
    Rand1 = random.randint(5,10)#First Random Number
    Rand2 = random.randint(1,5)#Second Random Number
    while QuestionsAsked < :#Checks if the number if questions asked is more than 10
    question = Rand1 random.choice(operation) Rand2
```

I would like to be able to follow my operations list exactly 10 times while the numbers are being randomly generated.

Comment: Hello, on StackOverflow it is required of you to describe where you fail. So far it could as well look like you wrote half of the code and - losing interest - ask us to finish it.

Comment: I am failing to get my question to be able too create the questions following the order of operations which is stated in my operations array.